# Parse CSV with headers into associative array, echo to serial port(Arduino) and display summary on screen

Tags: php, arrays, csv, serial-port, filesystems

I'm building a time lapse control device with an Arduino and I need a script to take my preprogrammed time lapse sequences from a CSV and output a summary to screen on the terminal and also echo the CSV contents to the serial port for an Arduino to process. The Arduino will have a camera and a stepper motor controlled gymbal that will move according to the values in the csv.

This is all via php-cli and not a web interface because this will be built into a custom case and I will want to run it on a headless raspberry pi via ssh, no GUIs will be needed.

The CSV to be parsed might look like this, this is an example of a 60 minute time lapse sequence with photos being taken every 10 minutes.

```
Movement#,Pan(Degrees),Tilt(Degrees),Slide(mm),Delay(Seconds),Shoot,Flash
1,0,5,0,300,1,1
2,15,10,100,600,1,1
3,30,15,200,600,1,1
4,45,20,300,600,1,1
5,60,25,400,600,1,1
6,75,30,500,600,1,1
```

The "Movement#" header is only in place for "photographic troubleshooting" I don't want to use it for any processing.
I want the script to count the lines of csv to return the movements and also sum the Delay values for a total time in HH:MM:SS.

In the above example the output to the screen would be

```
Movements: 6
Total Time: 01:00:00
```

I'm also trying to use an associative array because I'll be doing other things with the array as I build more functionality into this setup. It also seems to make sense because when the totalling of time is being done,  a sum of only that field can be run.

In the same example, the output to the serial port(Arduino) would be of the values under these headers.

The bracketed units I listed above are only to help with understanding the goals as described in this question, I don't need to include them in the actual header values that get stored and sent to the Arduino.

This is what would be sent to the Arduino so it can process these instructions to control camera movements, shutter release, flash operations and delay timing.

```
Pan,Tilt,Slide,Delay,Shoot,Flash
0,5,0,300,1,1
15,10,100,300,1,1
30,15,200,300,1,1
45,20,300,300,1,1
60,25,400,300,1,1
75,30,500,300,1,1
```

I have some code that I've tried to hack together, but I have had so many problems with it I'm not sure if any of it is any use. It's currently displaying values in the wrong order and if I try to put them in the right order, the variables aren't in place at the time things are processed.

//need to increment delay column into new variable that will be used to return total time of movement, probably goes in the loop which is processing each line of the csv

```
<?php

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("Movement.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$lines = array($data);
        $num = count($data);
        echo "\n";
        //echo "$num fields in line $row: ";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            //echo $data[$c] . ",";
        }
        $movement = $data;
    echo implode(",",$movement);

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
echo "\n";
echo "Movements:" . count($movement) . "\n";
echo "Total Time:" . "??" . "\n";
//echo array_sum();


?>
```

Comment: I've updated my anwser.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an actual answer (i am not allowed to post a comment yet), but this might help for parsing the csv

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
$num_move = 0 ;
$total = 0 ;
$lines = 0 ;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   if ($line++ == 0) continue; // remove header
   $total += intval($data[3]);
   $num_move++;
}
var_dump($num_move, gmdate("H:i:s", $total));
```